# In what URL segment do you have language? /en/admin/dashboard or /admin/en/dashboard?

Tags: localization, url

maybe you are thinking that this is another dump question about language in URL, but I hope it is not! I've red many articles on this, but non of them was dealing with "sections of site" (described bellow).

I am programming a new application platform in laravel/php and I am still not 100% convinced where to put language slug.

There are many places where you can put it - some of them are better some are worse:

- example.com/en/article
- en.example.com/article
- example.com/article?lang=en

My personal choice is to put language after the domain - so the first option in above list.

***But what if you are in some special secion like admin or api?*** where do you put language then?

- example.com/**en/admin**/dashboard
- example.com/**en/api/v1**/user/login

or

- example.com/**admin/en**/dashboard
- example.com/**api/v1/en**/user/login

(in frontend it is left the same: example.com/en/some-article)

what do you preffer? what are cons and pros? One thing is using language in first segments is far more easier to programm than when it have some variants...

**EDIT:** I am also using **two lists of avalible languages** to determine what languages are avalible for app/**backend** and for **frontend** (if the app is something like CMS). Eg. web can be only in english but app (cms) can be in czech, english, italian...

P.S. whould you recoment using only en, cs or do it in full power with cz-CZ, en-US ?

thanks for any thoughts!

J.

Comment: In the `Accept-language` request header. Translations are different representations of the same resource, so the resource identifier should remain the same. Apart from that, there are no rules, so this is pretty much opinion-based.

Comment: thanks for comment but I think it does not solve my problem. I am also using Accept-language header but only to identify potencial app language when language is not set in URL. This question is how would you detect switched language by user, where to put that "switch" - like click anchor that points to example.com/admin/en or that points to example.com/en/admin?

Comment: You're missing my point: using the language in the URL is semantically wrong. It is though a solution to the problem that no browser allows for easy `accept-language` switching, but it can be solved in different ways than URL manipulation. And then _when_ you choose to use URL manipulation, it doesn't matter where you put the language as there are no rules for that, so this question will only attract opinion-based answers. :-)

Comment: Thats true. I would maybe also prefer URLs without languages in it and just switch the web app by sending the desired language in POST data, BUT I think this is acceptable only for Apps and not for webs. You can switch language by parameter in POST in admin section or in first call in API, but when you want to send link to someone that points to example.com/about and you want to send czech version (example.com/cs/about) how would you achieve it? I think you can not do it in this example - only if you would combine it example.com/cs/about would redirect to example.com/about

Answer (score 1):

For your developer-facing API, you should obey the `Accept-Language` header for the reason [CodeCaster mentioned in the comments](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218340/in-what-url-segment-do-you-have-language-en-admin-dashboard-or-admin-en-dashb#comment432935_218340):

> Translations are different representations of the same resource, so the resource identifier should remain the same.

However, for UI (i.e. anything where the user-agent is a web browser) using `Accept-Language` to decide which language to render the page in is probably a bad idea, since it is effectively unchangeable (unless you're in the 0.001% of users who knows how) and may not reflect your users' actual language preference anyway. Using `Accept-Language` to select the *default* language a user sees is a nice idea, but even [Google recommends that you keep the content for each language on separate URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#1).

As to your actual question: *Where in the URL should the language fragment go?* Well... It doesn't really matter. There are no strict rules for this. It will largely depend on what is easiest for you to implement in your chosen framework.

Here is some additional reading:

- [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/403/3812) (Webmasters.SE)
- [Working with multilingual websites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.se/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html) (Google Webmaster Central blog)

Comment: Thanks for that reply and resources - I found them too :) I am using example.com/cs/article for all the time, but what if you are in some sub section? in admin section, or in eshop? If the eshop is not in subdomain and the eshop is part of that app where would you put that language? I would say example.com/eshop/cs/ > this leads to use google.com/admin/cs/

Comment: @Shimmi Well, I personally like to put the language fragment at the very beginning of the URL because I think it is more aesthetically pleasing, but that's just my own preference. As long as you pick one scheme and be consistent it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: OK, i think it is just really a personal choise and there are (almost) no best practicies on this. And for the API, would you solve it by adding language slug to URL or to set language by API call? like call /api/lang/cs for the first time and then just call api/user/1/delete? my API calls also returns i10d message like "User deleted" beside the code: user_deleted. thanks!